# Can anyone help me understand why my CSS won't work on 1 specific wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress page that works perfectly except for the latest pages I've added to it. The custom CSS in Wordpress did work until it suddenly stopped working and I have validated the CSS file with no error.

Here is the .CSS file (or parts of it with my edits today):

```
    .page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #bigbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    background-color: #222;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 h1 {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 h2 {
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #scrollline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #222;
    position: static;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #product {
    width: 23%;
    height: 340px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    border: solid 1px #bf4d28;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #productpack {
    width: 48%;
    height: 340px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    border: solid 1px #bf4d28;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #name {
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #imagepack {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #downow {
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf4d28;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 .norm {
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 #boxhead {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

It does the excact same thing for these four pages. When i had three pages it worked fine but it all went to hell when I added the 4th and the CSS stopped working for alle of the pages .

Link to the site so you can se the problem: http://www.the-prototype92.com/planetary-rings/

I'm using google chrome btw :)

Comment: You need to make your question clearer. What do you mean specifically when you say it all went to hell?

Comment: Better, but still not good enough. Your CSS is clearly working otherwise you would be looking at an un-styled page. What specifically is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess I'd say you're confusing selector chaining.

```
.page-id-1276,
.page-id-1282,
.page-id-1284,
.page-id-1287 h1 {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

This is saying to have a -40px margin for the classes .page-id-1276, .page-id-1282, and .page-id-1284. but to also give just h1 -40px for all h1 tags found in .page-id-1287.

I think you meant to do this:

```
.page-id-1276 h1,
.page-id-1282 h1,
.page-id-1284 h1,
.page-id-1287 h1 {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Which applies to all the examples you gave. If I am wrong and you did indeed intend to select things this way, let me know and I will revisit this.